# verificar que el checkbox esta checked con Jquery

Tags: jquery

quiero comprobar que si el checkbox, esta checked  por ejemplo pinte un parrafo de color amarillo, y  si lo deshabilito, pues no entiendo como hacerlo funcionar, tengo este codigo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="num1">
    <input type="text" id="num2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">

    <p id="color">Test</p>
    <script>
        if ($('#checkbox').prop('checked')) {
            $('#color').css('background','yellow');
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Debes agregar el código en la función **change()** del checkbox en tu jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, para detectar cambios en tu checkbox utiliza la propiedad `checked` y con eso pregunta por el `checkbox`  si esta **chekeado**.

```js
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
if (this.checked) {
            $('#color').css('background','yellow');
        }else{
             $('#color').css('background','white');
        }


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="num1">
    <input type="text" id="num2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">

    <p id="color">Test</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a informarme  sobre lo que has puesto

Answer (score 0):

Esto debe de funcionar

```
<script>

        $('body').on('click','#checkbox',function() {
            if($("#checkbox").is(':checked')) { 
                $('#color').css('background','yellow');
            }else{
                $('#color').css('background','white');
            }
     })
    </script>
```

Usas el metodo on click para escuchar el cambio.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="num1">
    <input type="text" id="num2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">

    <p id="color">Test</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Amigo, bien tu solución y todo, pero que ocurre si checka el checkbox con la barra de espacio? o hace click en el text del checbox?, es correcta tu solución y a la vez erronea por lo que te recomiendo corregirla